# Can't open python scripts, asks to choose how would you like to open this file

Tags: python, python-3.x, helper

So I had python for a long time, but I didn't code just downloaded scritps and all that. I wanted to install python 3.7, when I did everything seemed to work fine, but my .py files didn't open.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjjcb.jpg)

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zn7w.jpg)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hrxn/e2180e3c34bbed2c2e7e

Or you can try this: https://superuser.com/a/1095608/587825

Comment: thanks, that helped me out alot, +rep.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You may tell windows what program should open py files with. If you want to open them with a text editor or a python interpreter installed, etc. Go to start menu and type "default programs", from there you need to tell windows what praogram you want to associate with py file